# SSRS extra header pages being printed

Tags: reporting-services

This is most likely an easy question to answer but for whatever reason I'm not seeing it.  I have an SSRS report (8.5 X 11) developed in Report Builder 3.0 SQL server 2008R2.  The report just has a header section and body.  The body consists of 3 tablix objects; each table can have 1:N rows and any of the tables can have enough rows to cause the report to print a new page.  The margins are all .25 inches and the width of the report is causing no problems.   However, when it is printed I am getting the 1st page with the header data and a page of table data, the 2nd page prints just the header data, the 3rd page prints the header data and the rest of the table data, and the 4th page prints just another page of header data. Why are the extra header pages being printed?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you still having this issue?

Answer (score 0):

What is most likely happening is that part of your report is too wide, and the extra space is printing on the second page. It's usually the report body (it can change as you add columns to your tables) - I would check that first. Just look at the properties and make sure the width isn't wider than what will print on your page.

If you're having trouble identifying which section the extra width is coming from, try changing the background colors on the header, body and footer sections.  Set each of them to a different color, then print the report to pdf.  You’ll see the colors in the pdf and be able to identify which one is too wide.

Comment: @snels, make sure you add the margins into your total width as well. If you have .5" margins and can only print 8.5" wide, then your report can't be wider than 7.5"